# Write Latitude and Longitude to Geotiff file

Tags: python, geolocation, tiff, gdal

I am basically trying to achieve the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922532/obtain-latitude-and-longitude-from-a-geotiff-file).

I have a set of latitude and longitude coordinates (with values) in the WGS84 coordinate system, that I would like to write to a geotiff (or just add to a gdal dataset) via the gdal python bindings.

For example, my starting data might be:

```
lat = np.array([45.345,56.267,23.425])
lon = np.array([134.689,128.774,111.956])
value = np.array([3.0,6.2,2.5])
```

How might one do this? Thanks!

Comment: are the locations of the data gridded or are they point locations on a map?

Comment: They are random point locations on a map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it is not in your question, it appears you need to project the lat/long data from the WGS84 datum to a UTM projection. This can be using the [ogr2ogr](https://gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) command line from GDAL using the two options `-a_srs 4326 -t_srs ????` (the target SRID). It can also be done internally with Python using the OGR module of GDAL. [Here is an example of use](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/19416/1872).

There are two *independent* ways to get a raster from point data. The first is to [interpolate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_interpolation) the values in data, so that the values flood the region (or sometimes only the convex hull). There are many methods and tools to interpolate values in 2D. With GDAL, a comand-line tool [gdal_grid](https://gdal.org/gdal_grid.html) is useful for this purpose, although I don't think it is possible to use from Python. Probably the simplest would be to use [scipy.interpolate](https://web.archive.org/web/20211028024944/https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#multivariate-data-interpolation-griddata). Once you have a 2D NumPy array, it is [simple to create a raster file](https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html) with GDAL/Python.

The second method of converting the points to a raster is to burn the point locations to pixels on a raster. Unlike the first method, only the locations where the points are have values, while the values are not interpolated anywhere else in the raster. Rasterising or burning vectors into a raster can be done from a GDAL command line tool [gdal_rasterize](https://gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html). It can also be done internally with GDAL/Python, [here is an example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31568/gdal-rasterizelayer-does-not-burn-all-polygons-to-raster).

Comment: I have found some code [HERE](http://monkut.webfactional.com/blog/archive/2012/5/2/understanding-raster-basic-gis-concepts-and-the-python-gdal-library/) that converts lat/lon points to UTM projected points and then pixels, which perhaps is doing some interpolation with `gdal.ApplyGeoTransform` to assign each point value across a given cell?

Comment: @shootingstars Do you just need a raster with a few pixels where the points exist, and empty space in-between? I.e., rasterize the points? What does the data represent?

Comment: That's right. Once I've "rasterized" them, or have them in raster pixel units, I can use the inverse interpolation method I linked to in my first comment. Is this a bad way of going about things vs. just using the gdal_grid utility?

Comment: The data are whale sightings along ship transects cover the greater part of the North Atlantic.

Comment: @shootingstars Ok, I'm pretty sure you want to interpolate the data, not rasterise it (these are different). See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use gdal_grid from Python. I am using it.
All you need to do is construct the command as if you were using it from the command line and put it inside a subprocess.call(com, shell=True). You need to import subprocess module first.

This is actually how I am using it:

```
pcall= "gdal_grid  --config 'NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS GDAL_CACHEMAX=2000'\
       -overwrite -a invdist:power=2.0:smoothing=2.0:radius1=360.0:radius2=360.0\
       -ot UInt16 -of GTiff -outsize %d %d -l %s -zfield 'Z' %s %s "%(npx, npy,\
       lname,ptshapefile,interprasterfile)

subprocess.call(pcall, shell= True)
```

NUM_THREADS option is available from gdal 1.10+