# calculate latitude and longitude from a geotiff image

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, gdal, geotiff

How can I calculate mean latitude and mean longitude of each block from a `geotiff` image separating it into regular blocks (say, 50 by 50 pixels).

The input data is just the imagery,for example as downloaded from: http://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/57000/57752/land_shallow_topo_2048.tif

This can be opened into python using gdal as folows:

```
import gdal
geotiff = gdal.Open ('land_shallow_topo_2048.tif')
colum_numbers,row_numbers,band_numbers=geotiff.RasterXSize,
                                       geotiff.RasterYSize,geotiff.RasterCount
print (colum_numbers,row_numbers,band_numbers)
2048 1024 3
```

Comment: What projection, coordinate system, etc?

Comment: @Mad Physicist it's simply geographic lat lon system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this question: [Obtain Latitude and Longitude from a GeoTIFF File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922532/obtain-latitude-and-longitude-from-a-geotiff-file)

Since your image is already in lat-lon coordinates, the following values should be in lat-lon:

```
gt = geotiff.GetGeoTransform()
minx = gt[0]
miny = gt[3] + width*gt[4] + height*gt[5] 
maxx = gt[0] + width*gt[1] + height*gt[2]
maxy = gt[3]
```

Now the size of a pixel is:

```
latPxSz = (maxy - miny) / row_numbers
lonPxSz = (maxx - minx) / column_numbers
```

The center of a 50x50 box that is `i` box rows and `j` box columns away from the corner is:

```
boxCenterLat = (i + 0.5) * 50 * latPxSz + miny
boxCenterLon = (j + 0.5) * 50 * lonPxSz + minx
```

If you are using some other coordinate system, you can achieve a similar result by doing the transformation from the other, similar, question.