# How to perform linear/non-linear regression between two 2-D numpy arrays and visualize it with matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

First I'd like to clear that I need to perform regression on data between a disease and a number of other environmental factors for a particular large country, so I have lot of data.

Now I have this data stored in `tiff` files and I'm reading them into `numpy` arrays through `gdal`. Each dataset is read into a `numpy` array of shape `<54L,53L>`. I have several such arrays for each dataset. And I need to perform regression between such two 2-D `numpy` arrays. The values in arrays are `Float64`. Here's an example:

```
[[ 162.32145691  158.19345093  153.15704346 ...,  123.77481079 123.63883972  123.6770401 ]
 [ 164.55152893  160.59266663  155.75968933 ...,  121.28504181  121.1164093  121.16275024] ..., 
 [ 321.38272095  329.53326416  338.85699463 ...,  193.69404602   192.50938416  191.42672729]]
```

Like DiseaseDataset vs EnvironmentFactor1, DiseasDataset vs EnvironementFactor2 etc. Since the relationship is rather unknown, arbitrary and complex I want to plot these 2-D arrays first, but I could not find an appropriate way.

**So how do I plot the 2-D arrays in a scatter plot in `matplotlib`** I said scatter plot because it'd be easier for me to infer the relationship and move onto appropriate regression model (linear, non-linear, logarithmic etc). I used following code to plot the relationship row-wise between each numpy array:

```
for i in range(55):
    plt.scatter(JanTemp[i],can02[i])    
    plt.title('Disease vs Temperature')
    plt.ylabel('DiseaseCases')
    plt.xlabel('Temp')
    plt.show()
```

Here `can02` is the response variable and `JanTemp` is predictor variable. As expected I got 54 consecutive graph and in same color for both variables, which is frustrating (It's my first ever experience with `matplotlib` and I don't know how to get each variable its own color). **Is there a better way to do it? If yes, please suggest** I think it would be in 3-D visualization but then how would I will be able to infer from it? So please suggest a way to visualize in 2-D space but better than above.

Since I couldn't get much info from plots, I decided to begin with linear regression. I used `scipy.stats.linregress` similar to above iteratively for each row, in the following manner:

```
months =[JanTemp,FebTemp,MarTemp1,AprTemp,MayTemp,JunTemp,JulTemp,AugTemp,SepTemp,OctTemp,NovTemp,DecTemp]
for month in months:
    csum=0
    pcsum=0
    for i in range(54):
            slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(month[i],can02[i])
            csum +=r_value
            pcsum += (r_value**2)*100
    print "mean correlation coefficient is", csum/53
    print "The avg COD is", pcsum/53
```

Here `JanTemp`,`FebTemp` etc are each file of dimension `54,53`. For each file, I'm doing row vs row regression 53 times. This is also rather mundane. **Is there a better way to do it, like a function, module etc?**

The other method I was aware of was using Ordinary Least Square(OLS) of `statsmodels.api` module in the following manner:

```
y = can02
x = JanTemp
X = sm.add_constant(x) #Adds a constant to the linear eq of regression
est = sm.OLS(y, X) #OLS performs the regression of predictor on response
est = est.fit() #fit object of OLS fits the mode
est.summary() #Gives the summary of whole calculation
est.params #gives the coefficient of regression
```

But I get the following long error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Python\results.py", line 77, in <module>
est.summary() #Gives the summary of whole calculation
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py", line 1230, in summary
top_right = [('R-squared:', ["%#8.3f" % self.rsquared]),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tools\decorators.py", line 95, in __get__
_cachedval = self.fget(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py", line 959, in rsquared
return 1 - self.ssr/self.centered_tss
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tools\decorators.py", line 95, in __get__
_cachedval = self.fget(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py", line 931, in ssr
return np.dot(wresid, wresid)
ValueError: matrices are not aligned
```

I didn't get how the matrices are not aligned. Anyway, sticking to my original question, **Is there any other way similar to this to perform regression and how would I do it on 2-D arrays**
Thanks, I know I took a lot of your precious time in this long question but I wanted to be clear. I've searched numerous questions on this site and at other websites but I couldn't find an appropriate or related solution. Thanks.

Comment: Each position in the `(54,53)` array represent one geographic region? In that case I think you need spatial regression model. `python` might lack some of those methods, but do look into Generalised Linear Spatial Model (`R` package `geoRglm`). See an example here in this paper: http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0071574

Comment: Yes it does, but there are no coordinate lat-long values. But for example the (2,2) pixel in both the files would basically contain the corresponding values (say for disease and temperature) respectively for the same region. The GeoTiff file doesn't have the coordinates itself as it stores in (x,y) format but they can be obtained as pointed [by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922532/obtain-latitude-and-longitude-from-a-geotiff-file)

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually have have 3D data with axes location, parameter, year? Then there is very little geographical in this.

I do not think the problem is `numpy` at all, but the way how to analyze the data. (Toolwise you might be interested in `pandas`, as soon as you know what you want.)

There are some very sophisticated statistical methods for this type of work, but you may start with some simple concepts as you have done with the linear regression. First, you should separate the dependent variables (outcomes, e.g. diseases) and independent variables (e.g. temperatures) and look at one dependent variable at a time.

A simple example: Take just one disease. For that you have the number of cases at N locations during M years. Then take all P environmental factors you have. Now you can calculate the time series correlation at each location between the disease and all P environmental factors. This results in P numbers for each N locations.

If you show this as an image (N rows, P columns), you may look for columns with high intensity. They represent disease-environmental factor pairs which seem to repeat in many locations. This is not a statistically rigorous method, but it gives a quick overview.

---

I am not giving too many code examples, as the statistical basis needs to be thought of before making any visualizations. The visualization part is then usually easier. Unfortunately, there is no simple visualization for the type of data you have.

But for the scatter plot: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter . For example, to draw red markers instead of blue ones: `scatter(x, y, c='r')` If you only want single color per data series, you may also use `plt.plot(x, y, 'r.')` (`r` defines the color, `.` that we want separate data points.)

Comment: I've only one dependent/response variable and multiple independent variable. I need to find the way dependent variable changes with change in independent variable. The data is 2-D without third spatial or time axis. I already both `matplotlib` functions but I want one color for each variable (red for dependent, blue for independent etc.) while using `plt.scatter()` as I used above. As about the model I need to visualize to infer the appropriate model. Thanks.