# What does "~" mean in gdal?

Tags: python, gdal

I'm new in programming and I try to use gdal library for Python. I would like to execute gdalinfo command, but I don't know what "~" mean in "gdalinfo somedir/somefile.tif" example. Could you explain it to me?

Comment: Could you provide more information? What was the context?

Comment: `~` generally refers to the home directory of the current user.

Comment: ...you realise that `~` isn't actually in that *"example"*? In Python code, it's [unary invert](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations), in a path (as @karthikr points out) it's your home directory.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are looking at [Obtain Latitude and Longitude from a GeoTIFF File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922532/obtain-latitude-and-longitude-from-a-geotiff-file), the line is:

```
dalinfo ~/somedir/somefile.tif
```

Here the `~` is UNIX style shell expansion and is a shortcut for the current user's home directory.  The nearest equivalent on Windows is the environment variable `%HOMEDIR%`.

On UNIX style systems it is also represented by the environment variable value `$HOME`.

The user's home directory is the current directory ("folder", if you must) used when you first logon.  On UNIX systems it holds files containing user preferences and start-up files, often using filenames beginning with a dot, for example `.profile`.  You won't see those using `ls`, you need `ls -a`.  The home directory on Windows is used, but many end-users are not aware of it, although some software products (particularly portable ones) use it.

The `~` generally means something completely different in a programming language, and cannot be used as part of a filename without invoking a shell.

In Python, to get the home directory you would need to read the environment variable, for example `os.environ['HOME']`.