# python - find coordinate in geotiff

Tags: python, geotiff

As a python newbie I am searching for help :) hope to find it here.

I have a Geotiff file. I need to find coordinates in the Geotiff to find the position of a thermometer within the geotiff (the thermometer has the coordinates -115.47083484975207, 35.75837483423 e.g.).

I have these geotiff information:

```
PROJCS["NAD83 / UTM zone 12N",
GEOGCS["NAD83",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221010002,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",-111],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","26912"]]
```

How do I transform the geotiff, so that I get coordinates in lat and lon? I have already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922532/obtain-latitude-and-longitude-from-a-geotiff-file)

But I don't quiet know if this leads me to a solution. I just want to know how to find to position of the thermometer in the geotiff. Any help is very much appreciated, please tell me if you need any more information!!

Comment: How did you obtain the reference coordinates? As I understand it, the problem is converting from one coordinate system to other, but without any hint on what could it be, your best option is brute force all systems until you find a matching one (if it exists).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What do you mean by without a hint? I only want to find the position in the of measuring device (the thermometer) in the geotiff.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have misunderstood the problem. You should migrate this question to http://gis.stackexchange.com/, since the people there should be more knowledgeable on this topic.

Comment: If you're using Python, you can give GDAL a try, that's what it's for, but if you _really_ want to do this manually, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47951513/is-there-a-way-to-extract-geographical-tags-from-a-tiff-image-using-javascript/75647596#75647596 is probably required reading.