# Is there a way to extract geographical tags from a tiff image using javascript?

Tags: javascript, tiff, maptiler

I am working on a project which requires me work with a orthomosaic map. This map is in .tiff format.
I want to extract the geographical information from that map so that I can overlay it correctly on a google map.
I am using mean stack for this project.

So my final question is:
Is there a way to extract geographical tags from a tiff image using javascript?

EDIT :
When I use the Maptiler(https://www.maptiler.com/) it automatically places the .tif file correctly on the google map. 
I want to know how it extracts the information and places it on the map so that I can do it myself.

Comment: can you provide your "tiff" example?

Comment: There is, the [tiff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiff) package (v3 at the time of this question, v5 at the time of this comment) does exactly that, see answer.

Answer (score 6):

In order to read the TIFF tags, you'll need a proper TIFF parser, like the [`tiff`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiff) package, so that you can run through the non-bitmap parts of [an IFD block](https://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/egff.htm#TIFF.FO):

```js
import tiff from "tiff";

// Load a GeoTIFF file
const file = fs.readFileSync(`ALPSMLC30_S045E168_DSM.tif`);

// We can do this in the browser, too, the `decode` function takes an ArrayBuffer
const image = tiff.decode(file.buffer);

// get the first IFD block's pixels and fields
const { data:pixels, fields, width, height } = image[0];

// let's see what tags apply
console.log(fields);
```

yields (for this specific GeoTIFF):

```
Map(19) {
  254 => 0,
  256 => 3600,
  257 => 3600,
  258 => 16,
  259 => 1,
  262 => 1,
  273 => Uint32Array(3600) [
    ... 3600 more items
  ],
  274 => 1,
  277 => 1,
  278 => 1,
  279 => Uint32Array(3600) [
    ... 3600 more items
  ],
  282 => 1,
  283 => 1,
  284 => 1,
  339 => 2,
  33550 => Float64Array(3) [
    0.0002777777777777778,
    0.0002777777777777778,
    0
  ],
  33922 => Float64Array(6) [
    0,
    0,
    0,
    168,
    -44,
    0
  ],
  34735 => Uint16Array(24) [
       1,    1,    0,    5,
    1024,    0,    1,    2,
    1025,    0,    1,    1,
    2048,    0,    1, 4326,
    2052,    0,    1, 9001,
    2054,    0,    1, 9102
  ],
  34737 => 'WGS-84'
}
```

> I want to know how it extracts the information and places it on the map so that I can do it myself.

*Strap in, this is going to get detailed.*

The tag numbers are all well-defined things, and can be found listed over on https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags.html, where all the low numbered ones are universal TIFF tags (256 and 257 are the image width and height, 274 is "is this image rotated", 284 tells us whether pixels are stored RGBRGBetc or as separate R, G, and B arrays, etc.) and the higher number ones are "private" tags, only used in specific context. So for example that `339` tells us pixels store signed integers using two's complement, `33550` is the [model pixel scale](https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/modelpixelscaletag.html) tag, `34737` is the [GeoASCII params](https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/geoasciiparamstag.html) tag, etc.

In this, 34735 is arguably the most important tag, as it houses the [GeoKey dictionary](http://geotiff.maptools.org/spec/geotiff2.4.html) that is used by mapping software to properly place images:

The first line, `1 1 0 5`, reads:

- "Tiff version 1",
- "keys revision 1.0" (encoded as separate "before the period" and "after the period" integer values),
- "there are [5 entries](http://geotiff.maptools.org/spec/geotiff6.html) in this dictionary"

Each entry in the GeoKey dictionary is ordered as "key, tifftaglocation, count, value(s)", with the `tifftaglocation` field being either 0 (all "value" fields use SHORT, an unsigned 16 bit integer datatype) or 1 (the tiff tag's formal specification tells you how to decode the value), with the `count` field telling us how many SHORTs the value consists of.

In this case:

- 1024 ([model type](http://geotiff.maptools.org/spec/geotiff6.html#6.3.1.1)) has value 2: the data represents a mapping based on the Geographic latitude-longitude System.
- 1025 ([raster type](http://geotiff.maptools.org/spec/geotiff6.html#6.3.1.2)) has value 1: Each pixel represents an area (e.g it's an averaged height map, as opposed to a pixel being a specific point with an exact known elevation, but at that point only)
- 2048 ([geographic type](http://geotiff.maptools.org/spec/geotiff6.html#6.3.2.1)) has value 4326: This is WGS84 data, e.g. it uses (Web) Mercator projection, used by pretty much all mapling software
- 2052 ([linear units](http://geotiff.maptools.org/spec/geotiff6.html#6.3.1.3)) has value 9001: The data uses EPSG Linear Units (i.e. "decimal degrees" so a value of 38.25 means 38 whole units plus a quarter of a unit)
- 2054 ([angular units](http://geotiff.maptools.org/spec/geotiff6.html#6.3.1.4)) has value 9102: The angular aspect of the data is "degrees of arc", so combined with the previous value we know that if we see 38.25 that means 38.25 * 1 arc degree.

For doing map-related things (in absence of tools that can automatically place your tiff for you), we look at tag 33500 (which gives us our map scale) and 33922 (which gives us our map translation):

```
  ...
  33550 => Float64Array(3) [
    0.0002777777777777778, 0.0002777777777777778, 0
  ],
  33922 => Float64Array(6) [
      0,   0,  0,
    168, -44,  0
  ],
  ...
```

The values in 33922 tell us that pixel index x=0, y=0 (with an unused z-value 0) maps to real world arc degree coordinate x=168, y=-44, i.e. S44 E168 (also with an unused z-value 0) and 33550 tells us that pixels in the image are spaced `1 degree of arc * 0.00027[...] = 1/3600 arc degree = 1 arc second = 30.87 meters` apart, in both the x and y direction, which lets us determine the proper translation and scaling for placing and aligning this data on a map.

It also lets us compute the "GPS coordinate given a TIFF pixel" and "TIFF pixel given a GPS coordinate". Based on https://gdal.org/tutorials/geotransforms_tut.html:

```js
function transform(matrix, x, y) {
  return [
    matrix[0] + matrix[1] * x + matrix[2] * y,
    matrix[3] + matrix[4] * x + matrix[5] * y,
  ];
}

let [sx, sy, _sz] = fields.get(33550);

const [
  _px, _py,  _k,
   gx,  gy, _gz
] = fields.get(33922);

// Just like SVG or <canvas>, GeoTIFF uses a "flipped" y coordinate.
sy = -sy;

// Our "forward transform" goes from pixels to geographic coordinate,
// and is the (partial) matrix from the link above.
const pixel_to_geo = [
  gx,  sx,   0,
  gy,   0,  sy
];

// Our "reverse transform" is literally the inverse matrix operation,
// converting geographic coordinates to pixels. 
const geo_to_pixel = [
  -gx/sx,  1/sx,   0,
  -gy/sy,   0,    1/sy
];

function pixelToGeo(x, y) {
  const [lat, long] = transform(pixel_to_geo, x, y);
  return { lat, long };
}

function geoToPixel(long, lat) {
  const [x, y] = transform(geo_to_pixel, long, lat);
  return { x: x|0, y: y|0 };
}
```

(the transform reversal is explained over on https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/452575/219296)

Using this code, we can convert from GPS coordinate to pixel coordinate and back. For example, running the following code:

```js
const lat = 168.321971;
const long = -44.9856891;
const { x, y } = geoToPixel(long, lat);
const elevation  = pixels[x + y * width];
console.log(`GPS: (${lat},${long}), PX: (${x},${y}), elevation: ${elevation}m`);
```

yields the following log for the above TIFF data:

```
GPS: (-44.9856891,168.321971), PX: (1159,3548), elevation: 1421m
```

Or going the other way:

```js
const [ x, y ] = [
  (Math.random() * width)|0,
  (Math.random() * height)|0
];
const { lat, long } = pixelToGeo(x, y);
console.log(`PX: (${x},${y}) maps to GPS: (${lat},${long})`);
```

yields the following log for the above TIFF data:

```
PX: (278,1882) maps to GPS: (-44.522777777777776,168.07722222222222)
```

Comment: Wow! What an incredibly detailed and useful answer! Thanks for this!

Comment: I found this question at the same time I had to implement GeoTiff parsing in Node myself, so it has the benefit of catching me right when I knew the most about hand-parsing this kind of data =D

Comment: Great answer, have you thought about creating a NPM package? I guess it would be successful since there's nothing available

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call https://www.npmjs.com/package/geotiff "nothing"? That said, if you have "highly custom" needs, then a library will either do the wrong thing, or it will do way too much, so this answer kind of fills that middle ground where folks _don't_ want a library, but do need to work with geotiff information (especially because you almost never want to want to work with the actual TIFF image. Nothing supports TIFF, and they're stupid huge. Get the geo metadata, convert the TIFF to PNG, then for everyone's sanity: work with _that_ =D)

Answer (score -1):

If you are working with GeoTIFF, see @Mike's answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75647596/1192115
it describes in detail how to get geotags

If you have a PhotoCam that has images in a TIFF format and you need to extract where it was made, you can check [EXIF](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exif).
To do it you can use [exif npm library][3]

```
const ExifImage = require('exif').ExifImage;
 
try {
    new ExifImage({ image : 'your.tiff' }, function (error, exifData) {
        if (error)
            console.log('Error: '+error.message);
        else {
            let location = exifData.gps || 'who knows, maybe somwhere else :(';
            console.log(location); // pass location to google maps after some transforming 
        } 
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
}
```

Comment: I used this library it shows that no exif data is present in the image. But when I use the Maptiler(https://www.maptiler.com/) it automatically places the .tif file correctly on the google map. I want to know how it extracts the information and places it on the map so that I can do it myself.

Comment: @mistletoe, please provide your example image and a code sample of how you used lib, maptiler seems other sort of app, not sure of what it actually doing, seems like just break image on tiles or search tile on a bigger image...

Comment: "But I suppose you are mean to get EXIF" is the problem: this is about [TIFF tags](https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags.html), something that's baked into the TIFF image file format. It has nothing to do with EXIF, IPTC, or other third party metadata formats.

Comment: Note that even with your edits, the GPS information provided by EXIF (if there were any, because GeoTIFF does not use EXIF) is _not enough_ to do what the original question asked for, as you either need four GPS coordinates (one for each corner of the image) for a mapping transform, or one corner GPS coordinate and two values that let you derive the GPS coordinates for the other three corners. EXIF GPS information only gives "the GPS coordinate for this image", in the assumption that the image is a photograph taken at a specific location, which GeoTIFF very much is not.

Comment: you're right, but maybe there could be another one that could confuse GeoTIFF with an ordinal photo, so I'll leave this answer there

Answer (score -1):

There is open source library called open layers https://openlayers.org/. This is the best way to overlay your tiff image and once to include the tiff image on the this layer you can extract any information you need.

You can use Angular with typescript or java script, that is preferable. Basically you can get each and every details in a manner of coordinates from your tiff image using this library.

Setting up this library is an complecated project I just gave you an idea how you can accopmlish. I would like to help you in this matter. I know this is not much I explained and I cant give yo much details since I do not know detail about this problem. If you need any help contact me.