# How to read a .tif file using React.js or other Javascsript libraries?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tiff, geotiff

I want to read .tif files in my web program. I prefer to do it using react.js or something that will work with react. However, any javascript-based solution is good. The files I want to read contain geolocation-bound information. They have color coding for each pixel whose position is defined by longitude and latitude.

Comment: The real question is "why?", given that browsers don't have TIFF support, so the more sensible thing would be to convert your TIFF files to PNG on the server (since PNG can do lossless compression, unlike JPG) and then serve the PNG instead so that you don't need to do anything special client-side?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using react native and used a different approach for reading a geoid .tif for anyone that might find it useful.

I created a python program which creates a .db file that react native can read. This db file contains a matrix in which rows are latitude and columns longitude (Example: 360 columns, 180 rows means quadrants of 1 degree x 1 degree). Then mean altitude values are stored in each cell. Then in react native with some coordinates you enter the .db and find the altitude. This is a very approximated approach as i found it difficult to work with .tifs or .dems on react.

Comment: Note that this solution will be _huge_ compared to a compressed TIFF though (and _especially_ compared to a compressed PNG). Working with TIFF files is almost trivially easy given that [tiff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiff) exists and has existed since 2015 - and getting the geo data out is honestly [not that much more work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75647596/740553) if you know how geotags work.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const Tiff = require('tiff.js');

function readTiff(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      const tiff = new Tiff({ buffer: e.target.result });
      const canvas = tiff.toCanvas();
      resolve(canvas);
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  });
}

readTiff('file').then((canvas) => {
  // do something with the canvas
  console.log(canvas);
});
```