# Calculating the real coordinates of a .tif image via mouse pointer coordinates

Tags: python, tiff

So, I have a .tif image 7000 x 6000 pixels. I have read all the 4 corner's real LAT,LON coordinates, upperLeft, upperRight, lowerRight, lowerLeft using gdal python package. I use python code that anywhere I point the mouse **inside** the .tif image it shows me the x,y coordinates that represent the mouse coordinates which are pixels (x,y). It starts counting in relation to upperLeft corner that is (0,0 - the mouse pointer coordinates, not the real LAT, LON). I am thinking of taking the upperLeft LAT, LON (let's say LAT = 100000 and LON = 100000) and add something to find the pointer's real coordinates, but I cannot add real coordinates + mouse pointer coordinate pixels...I think you get the rationale... I have been trying many days to fix it without any success! My question is how can I translate the mouse pointer (x,y) coordinates to LAT, LON real coordinates, so I can add them and see the end result of LAT, LON that mouse shows in the .tif image?

Update (15/2/2021): From this link ([Find Latitude/Longitude Coordinates of Every Pixel in a GeoTiff Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63004971/find-latitude-longitude-coordinates-of-every-pixel-in-a-geotiff-image)) that you have posted I took this part of code:

```
def pixel2coord(img_path, x, y):
    """
    Returns latitude/longitude coordinates from pixel x, y coords

    Keyword Args:
      img_path: Text, path to tif image
      x: Pixel x coordinates. For example, if numpy array, this is the column index
      y: Pixel y coordinates. For example, if numpy array, this is the row index
    """
    # Open tif file
    ds = gdal.Open(img_path)

    old_cs = osr.SpatialReference()
    old_cs.ImportFromWkt(ds.GetProjectionRef())

    # create the new coordinate system
    # In this case, we'll use WGS 84
    # This is necessary becuase Planet Imagery is default in UTM (Zone 15). So we want to convert to latitude/longitude
    wgs84_wkt = """
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]"""
    new_cs = osr.SpatialReference()
    new_cs.ImportFromWkt(wgs84_wkt)

    # create a transform object to convert between coordinate systems
    transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(old_cs,new_cs) 
    
    gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()

    # GDAL affine transform parameters, According to gdal documentation xoff/yoff are image left corner, a/e are pixel wight/height and b/d is rotation and is zero if image is north up. 
    xoff, a, b, yoff, d, e = gt

    xp = a * x + b * y + xoff
    yp = d * x + e * y + yoff

    lat_lon = transform.TransformPoint(xp, yp) 

    xp = lat_lon[0]
    yp = lat_lon[1]
    
    return (xp, yp)
```

and I try to combine it with this part of code, that shows pixel coordinates of the image on a PyQt application:

```
class MyToolBar(mpl_qt.NavigationToolbar2QT):
    def set_message(self, s):
        try:
            sstr = s.split()

            while len(sstr) > 5:
                del sstr[0]
            x, y = float(sstr[0][2:]), float(sstr[1][2:])
            s = f'x = {x:.2f}\ny = {y:.2f}'
        except Exception:
            pass

        if self.coordinates:
            self.locLabel.setText(s)
```

like this:

```
...

 x, y = float(sstr[0][2:]), float(sstr[1][2:])
 xReturned, yReturned = pixel2coord('/Desktop/myImage.tif',x,y)
 s = f'x = {xReturned:.2f}\ny = {yReturned :.2f}'

...
```

But it does not work... I am trying to print real coordinates, not pixel coordinates and all them to be related to the different .tif that I import everytime! Any idea that is wrong with the code I show above ??

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129847/obtain-coordinates-and-corresponding-pixel-values-from-geotiff-using-python-gdal : Obtain coordinates and corresponding pixel values from GeoTiff using python gdal and save them as numpy array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63004971/find-latitude-longitude-coordinates-of-every-pixel-in-a-geotiff-image : Find Latitude/Longitude Coordinates of Every Pixel in a GeoTiff Image

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87642/convert-tif-with-tfw-to-a-geotiff: Convert .tif with .tfw to a GeoTiff?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162190/convert-tiff-to-geotiff: Convert TIFF to GeoTIFF

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am reading them! That's really a lot of useful input!

Comment: maybe try to cross post to https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That's ok, I will read the input you posted first!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: After  searching I see that the code never executes these lines:                                      x, y = float(sstr[0][2:]), float(sstr[1][2:])
xReturned, yReturned = pixel2coord('/Desktop/myImage.tif',x,y)
s = f'x = {xReturned:.2f}\ny = {yReturned :.2f}            But when I make this function a sepparate code on a new file: def pixel2coord(img_path, x, y) it runs correctly!! Any idea why?

Comment: does sstr = s.split() works ?

Comment: does while len(sstr) > 5:
                del sstr[0] works ?

Comment: so you have a tif or a geotiff as starting image ??

Comment: Yes, you are right it does not get into:  len(sstr) > 5: del sstr[0] . I have a .tif captured from UAV showing the ground/earth, so yes you can tell it a .geotif. Also it does not go neither to   x, y = float(sstr[0][2:]), float(sstr[1][2:])

Comment: my pyqt5 is long time ago, what does class MyToolBar(mpl_qt.NavigationToolbar2QT): do ? it is a standard pyqt5 module ? or is something you created ?

Comment: I gathered from a github repository, it basically shows the x,y coordinates (in pixels) from a loaded image. (source: https://github.com/Axel-Erfurt/OrthoViewLite/blob/main/OrthoViewLite.py). Please see line 46.

Comment: thanks a lot now trying to understand cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback they make really nice videos https://medium.com/@igorirailean/dense-optical-flow-with-python-using-opencv-cb6d9b6abcaf but as soon as I got spare time I'll try your code